# No type or protocol named 'GIDSignInDelegate'

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova-plugins

I am developing an iOS app using Cordova framework. I am trying to send push notification using firebase.

So I have installed "cordova-plugin-firebasex" plugin, "cordova-plugin-googleplus" plugin and I have installed CocoaPod too.

I am getting below errors in GooglePlus.m and GooglePlus.h files when I try to build in Xcode.

Generics issue in GooglePlus.h file

[image]

ARCSemantic issues in GooglePlus.m file

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Podfile informations below

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'my app' do
    project 'Hourglass.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging', '8.11.0'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :tag => '8.11.0', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions', '8.11.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Installations', '8.11.0'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '6.1.0'
    pod 'GoogleTagManager', '7.3.1'
    pod 'GoogleUtilities', '~> 7.2.2'
end
```

Can anyone help me why this issue is happening?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is defined GIGSignIn ? You may have forgotten to include some interface file.

Comment: Hi @PtitXav can you tell me what type of file am I missing? I have just installed the plugin successfully and I am trying to build the project in Xcode. I am getting above errors

Comment: Something like : #include "GoogleSignIn/GIDSignIn.h"